# Korean characters encoded in utf-8 that look the same(using print) at jupyter notebook, but are actually different

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, utf-8

I have a local folder called '안녕'

```
os.listdir("/Users/mac/Desktop/folder1")
```

> ['.DS_Store', '안녕']

I tried to write the folder name '안녕' to an image by Pillow, but the font turned out to be broken.
[broken font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeX0v.png) 
After a few tryouts, i realized the problem was that the '안녕' in ['.DS_Store', '안녕'] is different from '안녕' by manually typing it.

```
if '안녕' != '안녕':    #i typed the left '안녕', and copied the right '안녕' from ['.DS_Store', '안녕']
    print("they are different!")
```

> they are different!

Q: why are they different??

What I've tried:

1. I first thought they might have different encodings -> they both used utf-8

```
import chardet
print(chardet.detect('안녕'.encode()))
print('from os.listdir\n')
print(chardet.detect('안녕'.encode()))
print('manually typed')
```

> {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.7525, 'language': ''}
> from os.listdir

> {'encoding': 'utf-8', 'confidence': 0.99, 'language': ''}
> manually typed

2. -> but they had different encodings

```
print('안녕'.encode())
print('manually typed\n\n')

print('안녕'.encode())
print('from os.listdir')
```

> b'\xec\x95\x88\xeb\x85\x95'
> manually typed

> b'\xe1\x84\x8b\xe1\x85\xa1\xe1\x86\xab\xe1\x84\x82\xe1\x85\xa7\xe1\x8>6\xbc'
> from os.listdir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're folder was written using precomposed character

Use `unicodedata.normalize('NFC','안녕')` which decompose sequences.

Comment: AFAIK MacOS will always fully decompose file/folder names.

Comment: Thanks! Its my first time posting a question  here. I'm really surprised that your reply was very precise yet consice. I actually found my answer by myself, but it took like a whole day, while you answered literaly 10 minutes after I posted my question! Thanks again and have a nice day!

Comment: I just happened to face the same issue once ;)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason why they were different, and thought it might be useful for others, so i'll leave my post not deleted.

### macos encodes each vowel and consonant: ㅇ ㅏ ㄴ ㄴ ㅕ ㅇ
while jupyter notebook(maybe) encodes each word: 안 녕

b'\xec\x95\x88\xeb\x85\x95': manually typed
\xec\x95\x88=안
\xeb\x85\x95=녕

b'\xe1\x84\x8b\xe1\x85\xa1\xe1\x86\xab\xe1\x84\x82\xe1\x85\xa7\xe1\x86\xbc' :from os.listdir
\xe1\x84\x8b=ㅇ 
\xe1\x85\xa1=ㅏ
\xe1\x86\xab=ㄴ (The consonants written below the vowel : 받침)
\xe1\x84\x82=ㄴ
\xe1\x85\xa7=ㅕ
\xe1\x86\xbc=ㅇ (The consonants written below the vowel: 받침)

*useful link(content written in Korean)
[solution for merging the separated consonant and vowel](https://1023labs.com/posts/python-korean-unicodedata/)

use this-->

```
import unicodedata
text = unicodedata.normalize('NFC', text)
```

Comment: Although for Jejueo, you may still have individual jamo in strings even after normalising to NFC.